# In Word, how does one write around a full-page table?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

When a table appears in an academic journal, the writing usually just continues around it as if it weren't there. Here's an example

[[image]

- note how the text continues a sentence from the previous page.

I want to be able to position my table on a page, and then write around it, even if the table splits a sentence in half.

For example, page 3 ends halfway through a sentence, and I have a full-page table on page 4, and I want my sentence to continue on page 5. I imagine this is easy to do manually, but in a working document it would be better not to have to redo everything when edits are made.

This is the style that almost all journals use, and I'll be disappointed if there is no easy way of doing this. I hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you're after, then Word pretty much does it for you:

[image]

You just type your paragraph, insert a table and then drag the table to where you want it and the text will rearrange itself.

Comment: Yes that does work, but if I added a sentence or two after "Aliquam" then the table would move to the next page, so I would end up having to click and drag it up every time